# Is using uncompressed XFL documents with SVN advisable?

Tags: flash, svn, xfl

My team and I are considering switching to using the "Flash CS5 Uncompressed Document (*.xfl)" option in Flash CS5 based on the assumption that it will allow better collaboration and conflict resolution when working in a version-controlled (SVN) environment. We would like to avoid the common situation of irresolvable conflicts when multiple people edit an FLA.

Some casual research on Google has suggested that this approach may be fraught with issues, at least in the initial release of Flash CS5: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/645610

Has anyone had success or failure with this approach? Is this a favourable or detrimental change in workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use it in our team all the time and its amazing. It will literally swap out imported assets with others when changes to the xfl are made. Very advisable. And I can't report any failures.

**Edit:** 
I never ran into any of the issues marked there, I only ever noticed that sometimes it adds like little files for different things every once in awhile and so I had to keep checking those files out, but I never had conflicts with the DomDocument.xml and this is over PC and Mac too so I never had the other issue... Of course, maybe I was just lucky or it did get resolved later on : )

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Can you confirm that you have not run into the issues described in that forum thread? Do you suppose that they were resolved in a subsequent release of Flash CS5?

Comment: Excellent! I think I will give it a try.